# Почему не работает метод .data?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = document.querySelector('.block')

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log(a[i].data);
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  Привет
</div>
<div class='block'>
  Привет
</div>
```

Нужно вывести в консоль значение текстового узла элемента.
Почему такой код не работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) - возвращает **ОДИН** элемент, у элементов нет свойства `length`, поэтому в цикл даже не заходит.

Для исправления нужно использовать [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Однако, у элементов **НЕТ** свойства `data` - поэтому выводиться всегда будет `undefined`.

Какое именно из свойств нужно использовать, зависит от того, что именно нужно получить: text, html, или что-то еще.

Воспользоваться можно например свойствами: [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log('textContent', a[i].textContent);
  console.log('innerHTML', a[i].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  Привет
</div>
<div class='block'>
  <span>Привет</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы получить внутренний текст нужно использовать свойство `textContent`

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.block')

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log( a[i].textContent );
}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
  Привет
</div>
<div class='block'>
  Привет
</div>
```

Comment: Пишете "нужно использовать свойство `innerText`", а сами используете `textContent`. Как же так? :)

Comment: @Yaant ошибся), исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите получить список всех элементов, вам нужен [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), вовзращающий множество элементов. [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает только один элемент, и его нельзя использовать в цикле.